# How to convert a &str to a &[u8]

Tags: string, rust, slice

This seems trivial, but I cannot find a way to do it.

For example,

```
fn f(s: &[u8]) {}

pub fn main() {
    let x = "a";
    f(x)
}
```

Fails to compile with:

```
error: mismatched types:
 expected `&[u8]`,
    found `&str`
(expected slice,
    found str) [E0308]
```

[documentation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.str.html), however, states that:

> The actual representation of strs have direct mappings to slices: &str
>   is the same as &[u8].

Comment: The fact that this is the one of about five google results for this error message seems crazy to me! I hit this in my first test program post-1.0 (implementing "cat").

Comment: I was looking for a way to convert `&str` to `Vec<u8>` and landed on this question. For those like me, I found my answer at this question: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41034635/how-do-i-convert-between-string-str-vecu8-and-u8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41034635/how-do-i-convert-between-string-str-vecu8-and-u8) which gives a more comprehensive answer.

Answer (score 134, accepted):

You can use the [as_bytes](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.str.html#method.as_bytes) method:

```
fn f(s: &[u8]) {}

pub fn main() {
    let x = "a";
    f(x.as_bytes())
}
```

or, in your specific example, you could use a byte literal:

```
let x = b"a";
f(x)
```

Comment: I'd like to add that the documentation relates to the *representation*, but conceptually a string slice guarantees that its content is valid UTF-8, whereas a byte slice doesn't.