# How do I convert between String, &str, Vec<u8> and &[u8]?

Tags: string, rust, type-conversion

A new Rustacean like me struggles with juggling these types: `String`, `&str`, `Vec<u8>`, `&[u8]`.

In time, I hope to have an epiphany and suddenly get why some library calls use one or the other. Until then, I need help to map out each idiomatic transition.

Given these types:

```
let st: &str = ...;
let s:  String = ...;
let u:  &[u8] = ...;
let v:  Vec<u8> = ...;
```

I think I have figured these out, but are they idiomatic?

```
&str    -> String    String::from(st)
&str    -> &[u8]     st.as_bytes()
String  -> &str      s.as_str()
&[u8]   -> &str      str::from_utf8(u)
Vec<u8> -> String    String::from_utf8(v)
```

Ultimately I want a complete table of transitions for these types:

```
&str    -> String
&str    -> &[u8]
&str    -> Vec<u8>
String  -> &str
String  -> &[u8]
String  -> Vec<u8>
&[u8]   -> &str
&[u8]   -> String
&[u8]   -> Vec<u8>
Vec<u8> -> &str
Vec<u8> -> String
Vec<u8> -> &[u8]
```

Answer (score 187, accepted):

## From `&str`

- `&str -> String` has [many equally valid methods](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31331356/155423): `String::from(st)`, `st.to_string()`, `st.to_owned()`.

  - But I suggest you stick with one of them within a single project. The major advantage of `String::from` is that you can use it as an argument to a `map` method. So instead of `x.map(|s| String::from(s))` you can often use `x.map(String::from)`.
- `&str` -> `&[u8]` is done by `st.as_bytes()`
- `&str` -> `Vec<u8>` is a combination of `&str -> &[u8] -> Vec<u8>`, i.e. `st.as_bytes().to_vec()` or `st.as_bytes().to_owned()`

## From `String`

- `String -> &str` should just be `&s` where coercion is available or `s.as_str()` where it is not.
- `String -> &[u8]` is the same as `&str -> &[u8]`: `s.as_bytes()`
- `String -> Vec<u8>` has a custom method: `s.into_bytes()`

## From `&[u8]`

- `&[u8] -> Vec<u8>` is done by `u.to_owned()` or `u.to_vec()`. They do the same thing, but `to_vec` has the slight advantage of being unambiguous about the type it returns.
- `&[u8] -> &str` doesn't actually exist, that would be `&[u8] -> Result<&str, Error>`, provided via `str::from_utf8(u)`

  - `str::from_utf8(u).unwrap()` works, but you should prefer better error handling (see [Error handling - The Result type](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/error-handling.html#the-result-type)).
- `&[u8] -> String` is the combination of `&[u8] -> Result<&str, Error> -> Result<String, Error>`

  - `String::from_utf8(u).unwrap()` works, but prefer better error handling (see [Error handling - The Result type](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/error-handling.html#the-result-type) and also [`Result::map`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/result/enum.Result.html#method.map).

## From `Vec<u8>`

- `Vec<u8> -> &[u8]` should be just `&v` where coercion is available, or `as_slice` where it's not.
- `Vec<u8> -> &str` is the same as `Vec<u8> -> &[u8] -> Result<&str, Error>` i.e. `str::from_utf8(&v)`

  - `str::from_utf8(&v).unwrap()` works, but prefer better error handling (see [Error handling - The Result type](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/error-handling.html#the-result-type))
- `Vec<u8> -> String` doesn't actually exist, that would be `Vec<u8> -> Result<String, Error>` via `String::from_utf8(v)`

  - `String::from_utf8(v).unwrap()` works, but prefer better error handling (see [Error handling - The Result type](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/error-handling.html#the-result-type)).

Coercion is available whenever the target is not generic but explicitly typed as `&str` or `&[u8]`, respectively. The Rustonomicon has a chapter on [coercions](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nomicon/coercions.html) with more details about coercion sites.

---

#### tl;dr

```
&str    -> String  | String::from(s) or s.to_string() or s.to_owned()
&str    -> &[u8]   | s.as_bytes()
&str    -> Vec<u8> | s.as_bytes().to_vec() or s.as_bytes().to_owned()
String  -> &str    | &s if possible* else s.as_str()
String  -> &[u8]   | s.as_bytes()
String  -> Vec<u8> | s.into_bytes()
&[u8]   -> &str    | s.to_vec() or s.to_owned()
&[u8]   -> String  | std::str::from_utf8(s).unwrap(), but don't**
&[u8]   -> Vec<u8> | String::from_utf8(s).unwrap(), but don't**
Vec<u8> -> &str    | &s if possible* else s.as_slice()
Vec<u8> -> String  | std::str::from_utf8(&s).unwrap(), but don't**
Vec<u8> -> &[u8]   | String::from_utf8(s).unwrap(), but don't**

* target should have explicit type (i.e., checker can't infer that)

** handle the error properly instead
```

Comment: OK, but how to change a single u8 variable to string? to_string() seems to not work, since it yells "no method named `as_string` found for type `u8` in the current scope"... What I want is to change a small number (like 32) to string "32".

Comment: @piotao for that you need to call `format!("{}", 5_u8)`, which returns an owned `String`.

Comment: If anyone else is wondering you can convert a Vec<u8> to a lossy String via `String::from_utf8_lossy(&*s)`