# How to accept &str, String and &String in a single function?

Tags: string, rust, borrowing

I want to write a single function, that accepts a `&str`, a `String` and a borrowed `&String`. I've written the following 2 functions:

```
fn accept_str_and_ref_string(value: &str) {
    println!("value: {}", value);
}

fn accept_str_and_string<S: Into<String>>(value: S) {
    let string_value: String = value.into();
    println!("string_value: {}", string_value);
}

fn main() {
    let str_foo = "foo";
    let string_foo = String::from("foo");

    accept_str_and_ref_string(str_foo);
    accept_str_and_ref_string(&string_foo);

    accept_str_and_string(str_foo);
    accept_str_and_string(string_foo);
}
```

Is it possible to implement one function so that I can do this:

```
accept_all_strings(str_foo);
accept_all_strings(&string_foo);
accept_all_strings(string_foo);
```

Comment: It looks like since Rust 1.35.0 the `Into<String>` variant also works for [`&String`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/string/struct.String.html#impl-From%3C%26%27_%20String%3E).

Comment: Yes, you're right, I've testet it with the current 1.36 version of Rust.

Answer (score 70, accepted):

You can use the [`AsRef<str>`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/convert/trait.AsRef.html) trait:

```
// will accept any object that implements AsRef<str>
fn print<S: AsRef<str>>(stringlike: S) {
    // call as_ref() to get a &str
    let str_ref = stringlike.as_ref();

    println!("got: {:?}", str_ref)
}

fn main() {
    let a: &str = "str";
    let b: String = String::from("String");
    let c: &String = &b;

    print(a);
    print(c);
    print(b);
}
```

The `print` function will support any type that implements `AsRef<str>`, which includes `&str`, `String` and `&String`.

Comment: @trentcl A `String` will not be copied, the ownership of it will be passed to the method unless you are using a reference.

Comment: My mistake, my brain mashed up the body of the OP's example with the signature of yours.

Comment: What if the function eventually needs an owned string rather than a reference?

Comment: @malthe Personally I typically just use `stringlike.as_ref().to_string()`, as I like having the same signature regardless of whether I need an owned or borrowed string. I think that might be a bit inefficient with arguments that are already owned strings, so if you want to avoid that you can use other traits, like `S: Into<String>`.

Answer (score 15):

Since the 2015 rust edition the `accept_all_strings` function works as required by the OP with the `Into<String>` trait:

```
fn accept_all_strings<S: Into<String>>(value: S) {
    let string_value = value.into();
    println!("string_value: {string_value}");
}
```

Thanks to [Jeremy Chone](https://stackoverflow.com/users/686724/jeremy-chone) for the tip. The function signature can now be shortened like this:

```
fn accept_all_strings(value: impl Into<String>) {
    let string_value = value.into();
    println!("string_value: {string_value}");
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=release&edition=2021&gist=186903284aec83112122bb14baf1c013)

A really good overview of conversions between `String`, `&str`, `Vec<u8>` and `&[u8]` can be found [here…](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41034635/how-do-i-convert-between-string-str-vecu8-and-u8/41034751#41034751)

Comment: Does exactly what the OP wanted: [Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=release&edition=2021&gist=f0f56b4994b5c5c38b2e99f6534ee989) – so WTF?

Comment: Yes, this function accepts the 3 types of strings and does allocation only when it has to. 

It seems OP had put this option `accept_str_and_string` and perhaps thought you could not pass a &String. 

Btw, now, we can do 

`print(stringlike: impl Into<String>) { ... }`

which is a little shorter.

Comment: @Chone You mention the new ability of the `print` macros to capture the argument directly from a variable? I took the OP's request literally that he wants the `accept_all_strings` function. IMHO: To name an user function `print` is misleading and error prone. And I'm not sure if choosing `Into` over `AsRef` is just a matter of taste…

Comment: Sorry, my mistake, I did not mean to refer to the `print` macro. Should be `accept_all_strings(val: impl Into<String>)` as you noted.

Comment: I think there is a difference between AsRef, and Into. The former can only get a reference; you must do a new allocation if you want ownership. The Into will give you ownership without allocation when possible. I tend to use the Into for my builders/struct, as most of the time, I want ownership of the String, but do not want to require the caller to add .to_string() on refs

Comment: But `value.into()` will create/allocate a new String even if the function got a `&str`, right? (I guess it is unnecessary)

Comment: @DimanNe Besides printing an unmodified string, do you know of a second use case, where you don't need the string as owned?

Comment: @Kaplan, Yes, if I want to parse / find something in the input str/String, and return just that number/part.

Answer (score 3):

Both `Into<String>` and `AsRef<str>` (as described in the other answers) will accept `String`, `&str`, and `&String`.  They are different and which one to use will depend on your situation.

### If you need an owned string then use `Into<String>`

Using `AsRef<str>` here will rob your caller of the opportunity to avoid a string copy

```
struct Favorites {
    things: Vec<String>
}

impl Favorites {
    pub fn add_thing(&mut self, thing: impl Into<String>) {
        self.things.push(thing.into())
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut favs = Favorites { things: Vec::new() };
    // String literals are static references and we can't ever get
    // the owned value so a clone of the bytes is necessary
    favs.add_thing("hi"); // Contents cloned implicitly

    // std::env::var already makes a new string.  We avoid
    // cloning this value needlessly because we used Into<String>
    let my_fav = std::env::var("USER_FAVORITE");
    if let Ok(my_fav) = my_fav {
        favs.add_thing(my_fav); // No clone
    }
        
    // Note, there is a `impl From<&String> for String` which
    // makes a sneaky clone.  Watch out for this
    let my_fav = std::env::var("USER_FAVORITE");
    if let Ok(my_fav) = my_fav {
        favs.add_thing(&my_fav); // Contents cloned implicitly
    }
}
```

### If you just need a string reference then use `AsRef<str>`

Using `Into<String>` here will force a string copy where none is needed

```
fn count_whitespace(value: impl AsRef<str>) -> usize {
    value.as_ref().chars().filter(|c| c.is_whitespace()).count()
}

fn main() {
    let my_str = "he llo ";
    // Once clone of my_str is made here
    let my_string = my_str.to_string();
    
    // No clone of string data is made beyond this point
    let num_ws_2 = count_whitespace(&my_string);
    let num_ws = count_whitespace(my_string);
    let num_ws_3 = count_whitespace(my_str);
    dbg!(num_ws, num_ws_2, num_ws_3);
}
```