# Opposite of Borrow trait for Copy types?

Tags: rust, traits, ownership, borrowing

I've seen the `Borrow` trait used to define functions that accept both an owned type or a reference, e.g. `T` or `&T`. The `borrow()` method is then called in the function to obtain `&T`.

Is there some trait that allows the opposite (i.e. a function that accepts `T` or `&T` and obtains `T`) for `Copy` types?

E.g. for this example:

```
use std::borrow::Borrow;

fn foo<T: Borrow<u32>>(value: T) -> u32 {
    *value.borrow()
}

fn main() {
    println!("{}", foo(&5));
    println!("{}", foo(5));
}
```

This calls `borrow()` to obtain a reference, which is then immediately dereferenced.

Is there another implementation that just copies the value if `T` was passed in, and dereferences if `&T` was given? Or is the above the idiomatic way of writing this sort of thing?

Comment: I suspect the way you are doing it is the most idiomatic. Seems a bit overkill to create a trait for this use case only, especially when it is so easy to use `Borrow` instead.

Comment: I didn't quite understand the `Borrow` trait usage in this question but from the last sentence: "_that just copies the value if T was passed in, and derefences if &T was given?_" I expect that you need something like this:https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=4ee9d67e0bc483558e429fa35ffd3a51

Comment: What about [ToOwned](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/borrow/trait.ToOwned.html)? It calls clone, rather than dereferencing, to obtain an owned instance.

Comment: @张实唯 `ToOwned` takes `&self`, so it will always make a copy even if given an owned value.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is not really an inverse trait for `Borrow`, because it's not really useful as a bound on functions the same way `Borrow` is. The reason has to do with ownership.

### Why is "inverse `Borrow`" less useful than `Borrow`?

#### Functions that need references

Consider a function that only needs to reference its argument:

```
fn puts(arg: &str) {
    println!("{}", arg);
}
```

Accepting `String` would be silly here, because `puts` doesn't need to take ownership of the data, but accepting `&str` means we might sometimes force the caller to keep the data around longer than necessary:

```
{
    let output = create_some_string();
    output.push_str(some_other_string);
    puts(&output);
    // do some other stuff but never use `output` again
} // `output` isn't dropped until here
```

The problem being that `output` isn't needed after it's passed to `puts`, and the caller knows this, but `puts` requires a reference, so `output` has to stay alive until the end of the block. Obviously you can always fix this in the caller by adding more blocks and sometimes a `let`, but `puts` can also be made generic to let the caller *delegate* the responsibility of cleaning up `output`:

```
fn puts<T: Borrow<str>>(arg: T) {
    println!("{}", arg.borrow());
}
```

Accepting `T: Borrow` for `puts` gives the caller the flexibility to decide whether to keep the argument around or to move it into the function.¹

#### Functions that need owned values

Now consider the case of a function that actually needs to take ownership:

```
struct Wrapper(String);
fn wrap(arg: String) -> Wrapper {
    Wrapper(arg)
}
```

In this case accepting `&str` would be silly, because `wrap` would have to call `to_owned()` on it. If the caller has a `String` that it's no longer using, that would needlessly copy the data that could have just been moved into the function. In this case, accepting `String` is the more flexible option, because it allows the caller to decide whether to make a clone or pass an existing `String`. Having an "inverse `Borrow`" trait would not add any flexibility that `arg: String` does not already provide.

But `String` isn't always the most ergonomic argument, because there are several different kinds of string: `&str`, `Cow<str>`, `Box<str>`... We can make `wrap` a little more ergonomic by saying it accepts anything that can be converted `into` a `String`.

```
fn wrap<T: Into<String>>(arg: T) -> Wrapper {
    Wrapper(arg.into())
}
```

This means you can call it like `wrap("hello, world")` without having to call `.to_owned()` on the literal. Which is not really a *flexibility* win -- the caller can always call `.into()` instead without loss of generality -- but it is an *ergonomic* win.

### What about `Copy` types?

Now, you asked about `Copy` types. For the most part the arguments above still apply. If you're writing a function that, like `puts`, only needs a `&A`, using `T: Borrow<A>` might be more flexible for the caller; for a function like `wrap` that needs the whole `A`, it's more flexible to just accept `A`. But for `Copy` types the *ergonomic* advantage of accepting `T: Into<A>` is much less clear-cut.

- For integer types, because generics mess with type inference, using them usually makes it *less* ergonomic to use literals; you may end up having to explicitly annotate the types.
- Since `&u32` doesn't implement `Into<u32>`, that particular trick wouldn't work here anyway.
- Since `Copy` types are readily available as owned values, it's less common to use them by reference in the first place.
- Finally, turning a `&A` into an `A` when `A: Copy` is as simple as just adding `*`; being able to skip that step is probably not a compelling enough win to counterbalance the added complexity of using generics in most cases.

In conclusion, `foo` should almost certainly just accept `value: u32` and let the caller decide how to get that value.

### See also

- [Is it more conventional to pass-by-value or pass-by-reference when the method needs ownership of the value?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61898884/3650362)

---

¹ For this particular function you'd probably want `AsRef<str>`, because you're not relying on the extra guarantees of `Borrow`, and the fact that all `T` implements `Borrow<T>` isn't usually relevant for unsized types such as `str`. But that is beside the point.

Answer (score 2):

With the function you have you can only use a `u32` or a type that can be borrowed as `u32`.

You can make your function more generic by using a second template argument.

```rust
fn foo<T: Copy, N: Borrow<T>>(value: N) -> T {
    *value.borrow()
}
```

This is however only a partial solution as it will require type annotations in some cases to work correctly.

For example, it works out of the box with `usize`:

```rust
let v = 0usize;
println!("{}", foo(v));
```

There is no problem here for the compiler to guess that `foo(v)` is a `usize`.

However, if you try `foo(&v)`, the compiler will complain that it cannot find the right output type `T` because `&T` could implement several `Borrow` traits for different types. You need to explicitly specify which one you want to use as output.

```rust
let output: usize = foo(&v);
```