# Is it idiomatic rust to accept arguments that `impl Borrow<T>` to abstract over references and values of T?

Tags: rust

I find myself writing functions that accepts arguments as `Borrow<T>` so that it accepts both values and references transparently.

Example:

```rust
use std::borrow::Borrow;

#[derive(Debug, Copy)]
struct Point {
    pub x: i32,
    pub y: i32,
}

pub fn manhattan<T, U>(p1: T, p2: U) -> i32
where
    T: Borrow<Point>,
    U: Borrow<Point>,
{
    let p1 = p1.borrow();
    let p2 = p2.borrow();
    (p1.x - p2.x + p1.y - p2.y).abs()
}
```

That can be useful to implement `std:ops` like `Add`, which would otherwise require a lot of repetition to support references transparently.

Is this idiomatic? Are there drawbacks?

Comment: From the documentation for [`std::borrow::Borrow`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/borrow/trait.Borrow.html): "*If generic code merely needs to work for all types that can provide a reference to related type `T`, it is often better to use [`AsRef<T>`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/convert/trait.AsRef.html) as more types can safely implement it.*"

Comment: @eggyal Sadly `AsRef<T>` is not implemented for `T`, so a function that takes `AsRef<T>` will not be able to accept a `T` by value.

Comment: You describe the perfect use case for `Borrow`, in my opinion. Your use case is quite similar to `HashMap::insert`, which also [uses `Borrow`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/borrow/trait.Borrow.html#examples) for similar reasons. I myself have used `impl Borrow<T>` when I want to be able to accept arguments as both `T` and `&T`.

Comment: As a general rule, I'd say no: if you only need a reference, you should only accept a reference and maybe use `AsRef` for more ergonomics. I do feel conflicted though in the context of an `Add` implementation, since most users seem to expect `a + b` to work even if only a reference is necessary.

Comment: in my opinion, it's not idiomatic. I suggest just using parameters that take  a reference. You can get a reference off objects you pass to your methods by prefixing a `&` to them. On the other hand, if you want a method to consume a parameter, then don't specify it as a reference parameter.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think there are two parts to this question.

###### 1. Is the `Borrow` trait the idiomatic way to abstract over ownership in Rust?

**Yes**. If what you intend is to write a function that either takes a `Foo` or a `&Foo`, `F: Borrow<Foo>` is the right bound to use. `AsRef`, on the other hand, is usually only implemented for things that are reference-like, and not for owned values.

###### 2. Is it idiomatic in Rust to abstract over ownership at all?

**Sometimes**. This is an interesting question because there is a subtle but important distinction between a function like `manhattan` and how `Borrow` is idiomatically used.

In Rust, whether a function needs to own its arguments or merely borrow them is an important part of the function's interface. Rustaceans, as a rule, don't mind writing `&` in a function call because it's a syntactic marker of a relevant semantic fact about the function being called. A function that can accept either `Point` or `&Point` is no more generally useful than the one that can accept only `&Point`: if you have a `Point`, all you have to do is borrow it. So it's idiomatic to use the simpler signature that most accurately documents the type the function really needs: `&Point`.

But wait! There are other differences between those ways of accepting arguments. One difference is call overhead: a `&Point` will generally be passed in a single pointer-sized register, while a `Point` may be passed in multiple registers or on the stack, depending on the ABI. Another difference is code size: each unique instantiation of `<T: Borrow<Point>>` represents a monomorphization of the function, which bloats the binary. A third difference is drop order: if `Point` has destructors, a function that accepts `T: Borrow<Point>` will call `Point::drop` internally, while a function that accepts `&Point` will leave the object in place for the caller to deal with. Whether this is good or bad depends on the context; for performance, though, it's usually irrelevant (if you assume the `Point` will eventually be dropped anyway).

A function accepting `T: Borrow<Point>` suggests that it's doing something with `T` internally for which a mere `&Point` might be suboptimal. Drop order is probably the best reason for doing this (I wrote more about this [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63470466/3650362), although the `puts` function I used as an example isn't a particularly strong one).

In the case of `manhattan` drop order is irrelevant, because `Point` is `Copy` (trivially copied types may not have drop glue). So there is no performance advantage from accepting `Point` as well as `&Point` (and although a single function isn't likely to make much difference one way or another, if generics are used pervasively, the cost to code size may well be a disadvantage).

There is one more reason to avoid using generics unnecessarily: they interfere with type inference and can decrease the quality of error messages and suggestions from the compiler. For instance, imagine if `Point` only implemented `Clone` (not `Copy`) and you wrote `manhattan(p, q)` and then used `p` again later in the same function. The compiler would warn you that `p` was used after being moved into the function and suggest adding a `.clone()`. In fact, the better solution is to borrow `p`, and if `manhattan` takes references the compiler will enforce that you do just that.

The fact `Point` is small (so overhead to using it as a function argument is probably minimal) and `Copy` (so has no drop glue to worry about) raises another question: should `manhattan` simply accept `Point` and not use references at all? This is an opinion-based question and really it comes down to which better fits your mental model. Either accept `&Point`, and use `&` when a caller has an owned value, or accept `Point`, and use `*` when a caller has a reference - there is no hard and fast rule.

###### What *is* an appropriate use of `Borrow`, then?

The argument above strongly depends on the fact that references are easy to take anywhere, so you may as well take them concretely in the caller as abstractly inside the generic function. One time this is not the case is when the borrowed-or-owned type is not passed directly to the function, but wrapped in another generic data structure. Consider sorting a slice of `Point`-like things by their distance from (0, 0):

```
fn sort_by_radius<T: Borrow<Point>>(points: &mut [T]) {
    points.sort_by_key(|p| {
        let Point { x, y } = p.borrow();
        x * x + y * y
    });
}
```

In this case it's definitely not the case that the caller with a `&mut [Point]` can simply borrow it to get a `&mut [&Point]`. Yet we would like `sort_by_radius` to be able to accept both kinds of slices (without writing two functions) so `Borrow<Point>` comes to the rescue. The difference between `sort_by_radius` and your version of `manhattan` is that `T` is not being passed directly to the function to be immediately borrowed, but is a part of the type that `sort_by_radius` needs to treat like a `Point` in order to perform a task ultimately unrelated to borrowing (sorting a slice).