# Does PathBuf::from(&some_other_pathbuf) clone the data of some_other_pathbuf?

Tags: rust, io, clone

I'm writing a `custom_rename` function that receives a `String` and an immutable reference to a `PathBuf`:

```rust
fn custom_rename(new_name: String, old_path: &PathBuf) {
    let mut new_path = PathBuf::from(&old_path);
    new_path.pop();
    new_path.push(new_name);
    std::fs::rename(old_path, new_path).expect("error");
}
```

Does the `PathBuf::from()` function clone the data of `old_path`? According to [*The Rust Programming Language*](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch12-03-improving-error-handling-and-modularity.html#the-trade-offs-of-using-clone), Rustaceans try to avoid cloning.

Comment: While Rustaceans do try to avoid cloning, using a `PathBuf` is explicit instruction to make a copy, typically because (as in the included code) we are about to modify the value or prolong its lifetime (e.g. send it to a thread).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, a `PathBuf` owns the data. The only way to own the data when presented with a reference is to clone it.

I'd write this as

```
use std::{fs, path::Path};

fn custom_rename(new_name: &str, old_path: &Path) {
    let mut new_path = old_path.to_owned();
    new_path.pop();
    new_path.push(new_name);
    fs::rename(old_path, new_path).expect("error");
}
```

See also:

- [Is it more conventional to pass-by-value or pass-by-reference when the method needs ownership of the value?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61898884/155423)
- [Why is it discouraged to accept a reference to a String (&String), Vec (&Vec), or Box (&Box) as a function argument?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40006219/155423)

Comment: Thank you good sir. May I ask why you'd use a `Path` instead of a `PathBuf`?

Comment: @robfuscator that rationale is in the second “see also” link

Comment: so what your wrote about `String` and `&str` applies for `PathBuf` and `Path` as well?