# Isn't passing `&str` bad for performance in Rust?

Tags: string, performance, rust

In general it's suggested to accept `&str` instead of `String` in Rust.

Let's assume i have a couple of functions and a `String` instance:

```
use std::collections::HashMap;

fn do_something_str(string: &str) {
    let mut map = HashMap::new();
    map.insert(string.to_owned() /* copying (expensive)? */, "value");
}

fn do_something_string(string: String) {
    let mut map = HashMap::new();
    map.insert(string /* moving (cheap)? */, "value");
}

fn main() {
    let string = String::from("123");
    do_something_str(&string);
    do_something_string(string);
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=e6b226303390b0ee2982fec7354538e0)

Does copying happen in `do_something_str()` meaning it will be slower/higher temporary memory consumption?

PS. i know i don't have to call `.to_owned()` explicitly and the following will also work:

```
fn do_something_str(string: &str) {
    let mut map = HashMap::new();
    map.insert(string /* copying (expensive)? */, "value");
}
```

But since a hashmap owns keys i believe it will clone it implicitly. Please correct me, if i'm wrong.

Comment: I'm assuming this post is related to this advice: [Why is it discouraged to accept a reference to a String (&String), Vec (&Vec), or Box (&Box) as a function argument?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40006219/why-is-it-discouraged-to-accept-a-reference-to-a-string-string-vec-vec-o) That Q&A is encouraging `&str` over `&String` not necessarily `&str` over `String`.

Comment: @kmdreko Isn't String/&str case different from more generic by-value/by-ref?

Comment: No, not really. `&str`, `&[T]`, and `&dyn T` are a bit special because they have different owning types `String`, `Vec<T>`, and `Box<dyn T>` (due to their unsized nature), but the advice for when to use `&T` vs `T` would be the same.

Comment: So what's the right/better answer eventually: `String` or `impl Into<String>`?

Comment: Up to you, really. There's no real disadvantage to `Into<String>` except that it makes the signature noisier. I wrote a tangentially related answer at [Opposite of Borrow trait for Copy types?](/q/63465672/3650362) which touches on the motivations -- it's really more about caller ergonomics than anything else.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> In general it's suggested to accept `&str` instead of `String` in Rust.

Not quite. The general wisdom is to accept `&str` instead of `&String`. That is, when you already intend to operate on a reference, the more general type is considered to be better.

If you need an owned `String`, it is in fact wasteful to pass a reference only to immediately clone it. Accepting a `String` in the first place leaves the choice to the caller: if they need to keep a copy of the string for themselves, they can `clone()`. Else, the caller just moves the `String` into the HashMap and no cloning is involved.

> But since a hashmap owns keys i believe it will clone it implicitly. Please correct me, if i'm wrong.

`HashMap` does not clone on insertion. That would require a `Clone` trait bound on `HashMap`.

`HashMap<&str, T>` would still "own" the key, but the key in this case is `&str`, not its owned equivalent (`String`). Naturally, this would prevent the `HashMap` from outliving the string that the key references. The following example fails the borrow check:

```rust
use std::collections::HashMap;

fn main() {
    let mut map: HashMap<&str, ()> = HashMap::new();
    {
        let key = String::from("foo");
        map.insert(&key, ()); // error[E0597]: `key` does not live long enough
    }
    println!("{:?}", map.get("foo"));
}
```

Comment: may i wrap-up it as "if you know it will own the instance, just accept it by value"? So it will help the caller move it if it's no needed afterwards or just clone it.

Comment: @4ntoine sounds about right, and a similar sentiment is expressed in the [linked question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61898884/is-it-more-conventional-to-pass-by-value-or-pass-by-reference-when-the-method-ne).

Answer (score 1):

Calling `.to_owned()` on a `&str` will indeed create an owned copy of the string and is associated with the corresponding performance/memory penaltly.

As you correctly noted, you can also have a `HashMap<&str, V>`, i.e. a `HashMap` whose keys are of type `&str`. This does not require cloning of the string.
This however means that the lifetime of the `HashMap` is limited by the lifetime of the `&str`.