# can't use implemented trait in other file rust

Tags: rust, namespaces, implementation

so i have got two files main.rs and utils.rs

I implemented StringUtils method on utils.rs but when I try to use the method in main.rs
it gives me this error

```
error[E0599]: no method named `slice` found for reference `&str` in the current scope
  --> src\main.rs:89:50
   |
89 |         let text: String = self.inner.clone().as_str().slice(self.start, self.current);
   |                                                        ^^^^^ method not found in `&str`
   |
   = help: items from traits can only be used if the trait is implemented and in scope
note: `StringUtils` defines an item `slice`, perhaps you need to implement it
  --> src\util.rs:25:1
   |
25 | trait StringUtils {
   | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

```rust
// main.rs

mod utils;
use utils::*;

...

    fn add_token0(&mut self, token_type: TokenType) {
        let text: String = self.inner.clone().as_str().slice(self.start, self.current);
        // error: no method named `slice` found for reference `&str` in the current scope
    }

...
```

but I implemented it already on utils.rs

```rust
// utils.rs

...

trait StringUtils {
    ...
    fn slice(&self, range: impl RangeBounds<usize>) -> &str;
    ...
}

impl StringUtils for str {
    ...
    fn slice(&self, range: impl RangeBounds<usize>) -> &str {
        ...
    }
    ...
}

...
```

why doesn't my implementation work, and is there any way to solve it or I can only implement StringUtils on main.rs?

Comment: Do you intend the `StringUtils` trait to be public (either to other modules in your crate or in other crates as well)?

Comment: How many arguments should `slice` take? You have defined it with 2 arguments (`self` and `range`) but you call it with 3 arguments (implicit `self`, `self.start` and `self.current`)

Comment: @kopecs yes, I was asking about that

Comment: @trentcl thank you for reminding though it still does give no method found error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A substantively equivalent example appears in the section [Paths for Referring to an Item in the Module Tree](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/book/ch07-03-paths-for-referring-to-an-item-in-the-module-tree.html#paths-for-referring-to-an-item-in-the-module-tree) in The Rust Programming Language (which if you haven't read, I would suggest).

The short version is that any item (e.g., trait, function definition) within a module that you would like to be visible to other modules should have some variant of a `pub` visibility modifier. In your instant example, this manifests as needing to make the `StringUtils` trait `pub` (or some other variant exposing it to the containing module).

In fact, if you attempt to import `StringUtils` directly, via `use utils::StringUtils` instead of a glob import, you'd get the following error message:

```
error[E0603]: trait `StringUtils` is private
  --> src/lib.rs:7:12
   |
7  | use utils::StringUtils;
   |            ^^^^^^^^^^^ private trait
   |
note: the trait `StringUtils` is defined here
  --> src/lib.rs:19:5
   |
19 |     trait StringUtils {
   |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Which would link to [this explanation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/error-index.html#E0603) of one way to fix it. So if we do `pub trait StringUtils { ... }` instead, there are no issues relating to using the trait.

You would still have the issue @trentcl mentions concerning the incorrect number of parameters to `slice`, and I presume `self.start..self.current` (or the inclusive version) should be the range passed instead.

Finally, there is an error relating to your type annotation of `text` as `StringUtils::slice` would return `&str`, not `String`. Depending on what you want, you should either change the trait and its implementations or take a look at [ways to go between &str and String](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41034635/how-do-i-convert-between-string-str-vecu8-and-u8) and the [differences between them](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24158114/what-are-the-differences-between-rusts-string-and-str).

([playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=ab2450c442b2eac5715631ef4b0e8869)).

---

You may want to have a more restrictive visibility modifier, like `pub(crate)` or `pub(super)` which restrict visibility to the containing crate or the containing module, respectively.

A more exhaustive explanation of this can be found in [the relevant section in The Rust Reference](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/visibility-and-privacy.html).