# How do I convert a &str to a *const u8?

Tags: rust

I have a function

```
extern "C" {
    fn log_impl(ptr: *const u8);
}

fn log(s: &str) {
    log_impl(s.as_bytes() as *const u8);
}
```

This gives me the following error:

```
error[E0606]: casting `&[u8]` as `*const u8` is invalid
 --> src/main.rs:6:14
  |
6 |     log_impl(s.as_bytes() as *const u8);
  |              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

The most similar question to what I'm trying to do is 
[Converting a str to a &[u8]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31289588/converting-a-str-to-a-u8).

Comment: I would check out the FFI module. For example there is https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ffi/struct.CString.html

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Rust strings are not NUL-terminated like most C functions expect. You can convert a `&str` to `*const u8` by using `&s.as_bytes()[0] as *const u8` or by using `s.as_ptr()`, but that will not be valid to pass to any C function expecting a NUL-terminated string.

Instead, you probably need to use `CString` which will copy the string to a buffer and add a NUL terminator to the end. Here is an example assuming that `log_impl` doesn't store a pointer to the string:

```
fn log(s: &str) {
    unsafe {
        let c_str = CString::new(s).unwrap();
        log_impl(c_str.as_ptr() as *const u8);
    }
}
```

Comment: This function probably doesn't need to be marked as `unsafe` and should instead use an `unsafe` block internally.

Comment: I agree. I just did that since it made the example shorter and it could still be copied-and-pasted to the Rust playground. I edited it to add the unsafe block instead.

Comment: Asking as a rust noob: assuming the `&str` originally comes from some `String`, could we pre-load the original `String` with `s.push("\0")`? Would this work or am I missing something?

Comment: @JaySullivan Yes, doing that would work and would be more efficient than using `CString` if the `String` has capacity for the 0 byte without reallocating. `CString` just does two things: checks that there are no 0 bytes in the middle of the string and adds a 0 byte to the end (which means it normally has to copy the whole string).

Comment: To avoid unnecessary heap allocations, instead of `CString`, I use [a function I wrote](https://github.com/jminer/clear-coat/blob/068f247ce84017583cc49a257d84e659137e6c4f/src/attributes.rs#L17) that checks if a `&str` already ends with `\0`, and if so, it uses it as-is, falling back to copying it to the stack if it's small enough, falling back to copying it to the heap (with the stack vs heap handled by the [`SmallVec`](https://docs.rs/smallvec/) library).

Answer (score 1):

`&[u8]` is called a slice in Rust, and `*u8` is a raw pointer. You can go back and forth between the two types using `from_ptr()` and `as_ptr()`.

```
extern "C" {
    fn log_impl(ptr: *const u8);
}

fn log(s: &str) {
    log_impl(s.as_bytes().as_ptr() as *const u8);
}
```

Comment: Rust strings are not NUL-terminated, doing this is dangerous with FFI.